# Ghost Keyframes - Missing Keyframes that are still working?

Tags: animation, keyframes

Hello Blender Community!
I've been animating this Llama with keyframes and I also added in some wiggle bones to the ears threw and addon. After I baked the wiggle bones for the ears of the Llama. I went on to animate the two characters. Then coming back to the Llama, I noticed there are no keyframes for the Llama except the wiggle bones.
If I don't touch anything the Llama will animate correctly, but if I add in a single keyframe for any bone, ALL the bones stop working and the Llama is left motionless except the wiggle bones and the keyframes I added prior to the baking of the wiggle bones.

Thankfully what I can do as a workaround is to duplicate the Llama and just create a second scene to continue this animation. (The duplicated Llama has the same problem with ghost keyframes)

Is there a way that I can take this Ghost animation and reinsert the keyframes? or somehow get these keyframes back into the rig?

I do not know if the problem is Blender, Wiggle Bones Addon, or my self because I have not found anyone with a similar issue.

Thank you for taking time to read this.
-Pooka
[image] [image] [image] [image]

Comment: I have that exact same issue, did you ever figure out the problem?

Answer (score 1):

that happens , with me also  ,actually thats not a problem with blender or the ad-don , its with you , you probably are not selection the correct object in your animation  you are selecting an object that doesn't have a key frame there , try selection all things and look if there is something having a key frame there and try deleting it , or you can also make a fresh keyfram there

Comment: Here is two duplicate Llamas
Llama : has the ghost keyframes with adding no keyframes.
Llama.003 : has one keyframe added to the kneck and head.

Llama : keeps his animation
Llama.003: Loses all animation in those bones.

I added a couple more pictures to illustrate this.

Answer (score 1):

The exact same thing happened to me. As long as you have the additive bake enabled for the add-on, it pushes all keyframes on the armature to Nonlinear Animations.

You will find your keyframes there named "NlaTrack" which you can edit by pressing tab while hovering your mouse over it.